# SQL - How can I sum up a column after the results have been grouped and filtered in the having clause?

Tags: sql, sum, having, intersystems-cache, having-clause

Here is my current query: The objective is to find accounts that have received at least $500 in deposits within 30 days of their first deposit. Some accounts have been closed and re-opened, hence the first line of the 'WHERE' clause.

```
select      Deposits.accountNumber,
            min(Deposits.transDate) as "first deposit",
            Deposits.transDate,
            CAST(DATEADD(d,30,min(Deposits.transDate)) as date) as "30 days",
            sum(Deposits.amount) as "sum",
            Deposits.amount,
            Members.accountOpenDate
from        Deposits
inner join  Members on Deposits.accountNumber = members.accountNumber 
where       Deposits.transDate >= members.accountOpenDate
and         Deposits.accountNumber = 123456
group by    Deposits.accountNumber 
having      Deposits.transDate between min(Deposits.transDate) and DATEADD('d',30,min(Deposits.transDate))
and         sum(Deposits.amount) >= 500
```

The problem I am running into, is that the last line of the HAVING statement:

```
and         sum(Deposits.amount) >= 500
```

is including all of the transactions for the account, as if there was no 'HAVING' clause. It is factoring in transactions that are excluded from the first line of the 'HAVING':

```
having      Deposits.transDate between min(Deposits.transDate) and DATEADD('d',30,min(Deposits.transDate))
```

Here is what my data looks like (without grouping by account number):

```
accountNumber    amount    sum
123456           $100      $6,500
123456           $50       $6,500
123456           $50       $6,500
```

And here is what I am trying to get to:

```
accountNumber    amount    sum
123456           $100      $200
123456           $50       $200
123456           $50       $200
```

Thanks in advance. My DBMS is Intersystems-Cache. A link to their reference can be found [Here](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL).

Comment: Not sure if your database supports it, but you could try wrapping the query in a SELECT.  For example:  SELECT * FROM (your query goes here) i WHERE SUM(i.amount) >= 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
select      filtered.accountNumber,
            min(filtered.transDate) as "first deposit",
            filtered.transDate,
            CAST(DATEADD(d,30,min(filtered.transDate)) as date) as "30 days",
            sum(filtered.amount) as "sum",
            filtered.amount,
            filtered.accountOpenDate
from        
(
    select * from Deposits
    inner join  Members on Deposits.accountNumber = members.accountNumber 
    where       Deposits.transDate >= members.accountOpenDate
    and         Deposits.accountNumber = 123456
    having      Deposits.transDate between min(Deposits.transDate) and DATEADD('d',30,min(Deposits.transDate))
) as filtered
group by    filtered.accountNumber 
having sum(filtered.amount) >= 500
```

With a query like that one you are first filtering your data applying the transDate condition then you can operate the filter on the sum of the amount

Comment: Please explain to OP and future readers your answer, so they learn the process and not just code.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. The only thing you need to change is that you have to SELECT * in the outer, and move everything into the subquery in order to get it to work. Other then that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We need clarification:
1. Are the 3 transactions you show all within the 30 day window? If yes, then the total is less than $500. So, this account should be skipped.
2. Since $6500 is the total of all trans greater than the open date, why even calculate it? You only care about the 30 day window.

Besides that, I think the disconnect is the date calculation in the HAVING clause. You use MIN in the SELECT, but use a totally different aggregate date calculation in the HAVING. I think you should take the calculation out of the HAVING and make it part of the WHERE.

Of course, once you do that, you'll have to take the MIN out of the SELECT.

Comment: Hello @teebark. To answer your questions, 1: Yes, those three transactions are within the 30 day window, and yes it should be skipped, but it is still showing up in the results as the Sum is showing as $6500. 2. I am not trying to calculate it, but it is giving me the sum of all the transactions that are produced after factoring in the 'where' but not excluding results in the 'having', hence my problem :). Unfortunately, that would solve all my problems, but my DBMS does not allow aggregates in the 'where'. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: In the docs for dateadd that I see, the first parm should be either d or day without quotes--can you try it that way?